# JQuery Editable Select for HTML support

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-plugins

Iwant to use jQuery Editable Select for HTML support (http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/blob/master/example/index.html), but i don't understand why when we select the fairst element after we can't select another element ???

This is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery Editable Select Example</title>
    <meta name="author" content="https://plus.google.com/u/0/+IndriMuska" />
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/source/jquery.editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style>
        body {
            padding: 30px 60px;
        }
        .sources {
            position: absolute;
            top: 65px;
            right: 80px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <h3>HTML support</h3>
        <select id="html" style="width:200px">

            <option>Audi - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.audi.com/" target="_blank" id="coucou" style="float:right" rel="nofollow"&gt;?&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>BMW - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.bmw.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.bmw.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Citroen - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.citroen.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.citroen.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Fiat - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.fiat.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.fiat.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Ford - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.ford.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.ford.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Jaguar - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.jaguar.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.jaguar.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Jeep - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.jeep.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.jeep.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Lancia - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.lancia.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.lancia.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Land Rover - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.landrover.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.landrover.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Mercedes - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.mercedes-benz.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.mercedes-benz.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Mini - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.mini.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.mini.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Nissan - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.nissan.it/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.nissan.it&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Opel - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.opel.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.opel.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Peugeot - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.peugeot.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.peugeot.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Porsche - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.porsche.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.porsche.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Renault - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.renault.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.renault.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Smart - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.smart.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.smart.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Volkswagen - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://volkswagen.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;volkswagen.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
            <option>Volvo - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.volvo.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.volvo.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/source/jquery.editable-select.js"></script>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        $('#html').editableSelect();
        $('#coucou').mouseenter(function() {
            alert("Hello");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It is because there is a filtering going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{ filter: false }` in plugin initialization, which will turn of the filtering.

```js
$('#html').editableSelect({ filter: false });
```

```css
body {
  padding: 30px 60px;
}
.sources {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  right: 80px;
}
```

```html
<meta name="author" content="https://plus.google.com/u/0/+IndriMuska" />
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/source/jquery.editable-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
    <h3>HTML support</h3>
    <select id="html" style="width:200px">

      <option>Audi - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.audi.com/" target="_blank" id="coucou" style="float:right" rel="nofollow"&gt;?&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>BMW - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.bmw.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.bmw.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Citroen - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.citroen.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.citroen.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Fiat - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.fiat.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.fiat.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Ford - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.ford.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.ford.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Jaguar - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.jaguar.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.jaguar.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Jeep - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.jeep.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.jeep.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Lancia - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.lancia.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.lancia.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Land Rover - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.landrover.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.landrover.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Mercedes - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.mercedes-benz.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.mercedes-benz.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Mini - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.mini.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.mini.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Nissan - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.nissan.it/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.nissan.it&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Opel - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.opel.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.opel.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Peugeot - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.peugeot.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.peugeot.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Porsche - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.porsche.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.porsche.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Renault - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.renault.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.renault.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Smart - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.smart.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.smart.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Volkswagen - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://volkswagen.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;volkswagen.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
      <option>Volvo - &lt;small&gt;&lt;a href="http://www.volvo.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"&gt;www.volvo.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/small&gt;</option>
    </select>
  </div>

</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/source/jquery.editable-select.js"></script>
```